# Asp.Net Connecting to existing Azure Database blocking IP even though it is allowed in firewall

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, azure, connection-string

I have a frustration issue with connecting to an existing Azure database from my asp.net web api app. I have gotten the connection-string from the Azure portal, and I have put it in web.config under connection-strings. But when I try to generate ADO.NET Entity Data Model using the connection-string named "defaultconnection" it tells me that my ip-adress is not allowed. But the annoying part is that it is set as allowed under the firewall-rules in the Azure Portal. In Visual Studio I am able to browse through the DB via the Server Explorer, which I think is strange if my IP is not allowed.

The error message I get says; "An exception of type 'System.DataSqlClient.SqlException' occured. The error message is 'Cannot open server 'live' requested by the login. Client with IP 'xxx.xxxxx' is not allowed to access the server'

This is what it looks like in web.config;

```
 <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:iotbackendserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=IoT Backend;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={***};Password={********};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

In IdentityModels it calls that connection-string;

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem is? I've looked through every tutorial that Microsoft has, and I've tried my best searching through the questions that has already been asked, but I'm still not completely sure how to access the existing Database in Azure and generate model-classes from it and then be able to use Code First migrations.

Comment: If you can browse the DB in VS, then your IP is allowed. Your error can also mean that the user you are trying to connect with does not have enough permissions. Try connecting to your DB with the exact username/password

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I also think it's strange that I can browse the DB in VS but not throught ADO.NET. Where are you suggesting that I reconnect to the DB? In Azure or in VS? I' tried restarting VS multiple times, and also signing in and out from Azure. There shouldn not be any issues with the permissions. Is this the proper way to connect to an existing azure database btw? Taking the connection-string and putting it in web.config, then use that from the DbContext?

Comment: It the right way. By permissions I mean SQL User permissions. Open SQL Server Management Studio, enter details from your production connection  string - server, database, username and password and see if you can connect there

Comment: I feel extremely dumb, but I blame VS aswell. So, in the connectionstring I had brackets around the username and password. When signing in with the Azure-credentials I only got prompted for the IP-access. Which had me believing that the brackets should be there since it seemed to be able to connect but not get access. When logging in to SSMS I noticed that I had to use the credentials for the DB, not for the Azure-account. I tried this multiple times before in the connectionstring and I got prompted for wrong username. Now I tried it without the brackets and it worked...

Comment: We've all been there. Kudos for sorting it out yourself!

Comment: You pushed me in the right direction my friend. Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions!